# plotting data from a txt file with excel

Tags: excel, plot

I have a text file that I will upload it. I wanna to select just 2 columns and then plot it with something like excel!
the problem is that when i want to select a column, those things that selected, is not just one column. I try it to open with excel. however it opened but there was same problem again. I'm just wanna select all data of one column and then plot it.

I can not even copy or a paste a certain data. all data will copy instead.

My English is not adequate, I know. Hope to could convey my mean.
Any help will be appreciated.

[file](https://file.io/1wXtbHsTnM8K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel, select the first column which should contain all the columns from your text file.
In the excel menus (or using the search field), select « convert ». Then chose the type « delimiter », and select the delimiter in your excel file. Either a comma, or a tabulation, etc.
Click ok and this should do the trick

Comment: Thanks friend for your help. But your guidance seems a bit complicated. I'm trying to understand it. I'm not profetional :(

Comment: https://adcogov.org/sites/default/files/7156.pdf       Try this link

Comment: Finaly, It's done. You have my thanks. :X